# Change a UIImage programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimage

i have 2 `UIImages` and a `UISwitch`, when the switch is on, image 1 appear and when the switch is off the image 2 appear... any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a UISwitch called myUISwitch and a UIImageView called myUIImageView:

```
if(myUISwitch.on) {  
    [myUIImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myOnImage.png"]];  
}  
else {  
    [myUIImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myOffImage.png"]];  
}
```

You can put this code in the function triggered by changing the UISwitch...